# error when running nosetests --with-gae with google cloudsdk installed

Tags: python, google-app-engine

nosetests --with-gae fails when running under the new cloud sdk.  It's looking for dev_appserver.py but looks like it's been renamed to old_dev_appserver.py.  I can hack a fix but is there an existing solution? Don't see one on the internets...

```
$ nosetests --with-gae --gae-lib-root=~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edahl/src/gmj/bin/nosetests", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nose==1.3.4', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
  File "/Users/edahl/src/gmj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 121, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/Users/edahl/src/gmj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 145, in parseArgs
    self.config.configure(argv, doc=self.usage())
  File "/Users/edahl/src/gmj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/config.py", line 346, in configure
    self.plugins.configure(options, self)
  File "/Users/edahl/src/gmj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 284, in configure
    cfg(options, config)
  File "/Users/edahl/src/gmj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/edahl/src/gmj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 167, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/edahl/src/gmj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nosegae.py", line 80, in configure
    from dev_appserver import fix_sys_path
ImportError: No module named dev_appserver
```

Here's what I see in my google_appengine directory...

```
$ ls ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/
BUGS            api_server.py       godoc           php
LICENSE         backends_conversion.py  gofmt           php_cli.py
README          bulkload_client.py  google          remote_api_shell.py
RELEASE_NOTES       bulkloader.py       google_sql.py       run_tests.py
RELEASE_NOTES.go_sdk    demos           goroot          tools
VERSION         download_appstats.py    lib         wrapper_util.py
_php_runtime.py     gen_protorpc.py     new_project_template    wrapper_util.pyc
_python_runtime.py  goapp           old_dev_appserver.py
```

The old /usr/local/google_appengine directory seems to be deprecated... but if I use it I can get things working.

[update]

a manual unittest setup using old_dev_appserver like this does work:

```
def main(sdk_path, test_path):
    sys.path.insert(0, sdk_path)
    import old_dev_appserver
    old_dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
    suite = unittest.loader.TestLoader().discover(test_path)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: In the release pipeline I see you can configure it to run python tests with nosetests so seems like it should work somehow

Answer (score 2):

In the end this was pretty silly... needed to expand the user path that's passed to --gae-lib-root

```
nosetests --with-gae --gae-lib-root=/Users/USERNAME/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine
```

Answer (score 1):

On my mac, I get this same error:

1. After an app engine update
2. But before I've run the GoogleAppEngineLauncher app since the update

The easy solution is just launch GoogleAppEngineLauncher.  This updates the sym links that nosetests needs.

Hopefully that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set your path to the lib folder under that directory:

```
--gae-lib-root=~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib
```

But you might also need to set your PATH variable so it includes the /bin as well:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/bin
```

If neither of those work for you, try adding the without sandbox switch:

```
nosetests -s -v --with-gae --without-sandbox
```

Comment: those didn't work... the issue is that dev_appserver.py has been renamed to old_dev_appserver.py in ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine.

Comment: old_dev_appserver.py was renamed a long time ago with a GAE release (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver).  The directory you'll want to point to is $CLOUD_SDK_DIR vs. $CLOUD_SDK_DIR/platform.

Answer (score 0):

According to the NoseGAE docs the default location it checks for the google-cloud-sdk is in `/usr/local/google_appengine`.

Moving the `google-cloud-sdk` folder to `/usr/local/google_appengine/google-cloud-sdk/` fixed this issue for me.

http://farmdev.com/projects/nosegae/